# How to convert the charset of system schema `mysql` in proper way?

Tags: mysql

While upgrading mysql from 5.6 -> 5.7 -> 8.0.23 in step 5.7 -> 8.0.23 I got a recommendation:

```
The following objects use the utf8mb3 character set. It is recommended to convert them to use utf8mb4 instead, for improved Unicode support.
More Information:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb3.html

...
mysql - schema's default character set: utf8
...
```

So, Is it enough to change the charset of the schema `mysql` to utf8mb4? Or at first, does it need to convert all the tables of this schema to utf8mb4?

Comment: Do you mean you are using the `mysql_upgrade` executable? Or some other upgrade mechanism

Comment: Those fields needs to be explicitly converted that explicitly specify a character set as defaults do not apply in that case.

Comment: I upgraded via aws rds, I think it uses mysql_upgrade under hood

Answer (score 0):

The way to change a schema's default characters set:

```
ALTER SCHEMA mysql DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
```

However, I don't know if your admin user on RDS has privileges to do that on the `mysql` system schema. It's possible that you don't, because RDS limits the privileges of your admin user.

Comment: Is it possible to change a charset of `mysq` schema in aws rds?

Comment: No. I have tested this on an RDS instance. Despite having ALTER privilege, the user gets "Access denied" when trying to `ALTER SCHEMA mysql`. I created a test user on my local MySQL instance, and granted the same privileges, and it worked. So Amazon has deliberately restricted privilege to alter the `mysql` schema.

Comment: In AWS, you can change the default character set through the parameter group which is attached to your RDS instance